# How to change the default group / specification in Swagger UI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

The Swagger documentation in my project has multiple groups. There is a `Docket` for each group and the endpoints (members of each group) are marked with a custom annotation. For example here is the `Docket` for **authentication** group:

```
@Bean
public Docket authenticationApis() {

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("authentication")
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(AuthenticationApiGroup.class))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securityScheme()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
}
```

There is also a (default) `Docket` for all available endpoints. The problem is that Swagger UI loads the most top group on default when I am calling the documentation URL `.../swagger-ui.html`. In my case it is the **authentication** group, since the groups are sorted alphabetically. The desired behaviour is that the **default** group is loaded as the default API group. How could I achieve that?

[image]

I have tried to name the default `Docket` with the `.groupName("all")` so it's the most top group (**all** < **authentication**) but this solution is a bit "dirty" and in this case the documentation would have two duplicate groups (**all** and **default**).

`Springfox 2.9.2` is used in the project.

Comment: From what I know there is no solution for this in springfox api. Another dirty solution that worked for me: if you have access to modify `swagger-ui.html` you can sort the specs with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

My quick-and dirty hack:

- I prepend "@" to make a group first in the list (hence default)
- I prepend "~" to make a group last in the list

Answer (score 0):

use **urls.primaryName** parameter in the doc: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/v3.17.1/docs/usage/configuration.md#parameters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).